# How to post a status update to Sina Weibo via OAuth2?

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, weibo, sinaweibo

I'm trying to post a [status update](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/update/en) to the Chinese microblogging website Sina Weibo, via PHP/cURL and OAuth2.
I'm running into this error:

> {"error":"auth
>   faild!","error_code":21301,"request":"/2/statuses/update.json"}

My PHP:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/update.json');
$headers = array(
'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,  
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$postData = array('access_token' => '2.00x123456789', 'status' => 'hello');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

curl_close($ch);        
?>
```

I authorized the app with the OAuth2 scope `all` and the token is valid.
What could be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your http header

`'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Replace post fields with:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData)
```

And now Be Happy!

Comment: I'm really happy now! Thank you so much!